# Libgdx Box2dLights: How to make light have a hard falloff?

Tags: libgdx, box2dlights

I am implementing a relatively simple game and I want the lighting system to work as if things are either in total darkness or total light, all the lights though  are bright at the origin and become progressively darker until they fade off.

I want them to be the same brightness at the edge of their range as at their origin, but I can't seem to find an existing option for this behavior.

If there already is a way to do this, please let me know. If not how would I go about implementing it?

Comment: That's pretty neat, but I don't think it is quite what I'm looking for. While I don't want the light to falloff due to distance I do want it to still be blocked by objects in the environment and I don't think that method supports any shadowing.